# Amazon : MWS Reports API Image url is empty

Tags: php, amazon-marketplace

Hello i am working with amazon MWS Report API for listing the inventory and i have successfully downloaded my inventory... but there is no image url under image-url column  it is tab delimited file...

Any one has experience with Reports API please help me with this...

```
$config = array (
  'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
  'ProxyHost' => null,
  'ProxyPort' => -1,
  'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
);

 $service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
     AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
     $config,
     APPLICATION_NAME,
     APPLICATION_VERSION);

$reportId = '8890052323';

$parameters = array (
   'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
   'Report' => @fopen('php://memory', 'rw+'),
   'ReportId' => $reportId,
 );
 $request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequest($parameters);

//$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportRequest();
$request->setMerchant(MERCHANT_ID);
$request->setReport(@fopen('php://memory', 'rw+'));
$request->setReportId($reportId);

invokeGetReport($service, $request);



function invokeGetReport(MarketplaceWebService_Interface $service, $request) 
  {
      try {
              $response = $service->getReport($request);

                echo ("Service Response\n");
                echo ("=============================================================================\n");

                echo("        GetReportResponse\n");
                if ($response->isSetGetReportResult()) {
                  $getReportResult = $response->getGetReportResult(); 
                  echo ("            GetReport");

                  if ($getReportResult->isSetContentMd5()) {
                    echo ("                ContentMd5");
                    echo ("                " . $getReportResult->getContentMd5() . "\n");
                  }
                }
                if ($response->isSetResponseMetadata()) { 
                    echo("            ResponseMetadata\n");
                    $responseMetadata = $response->getResponseMetadata();
                    if ($responseMetadata->isSetRequestId()) 
                    {
                        echo("                RequestId\n");
                        echo("                    " . $responseMetadata->getRequestId() . "\n");
                    }
                }

                echo ("        Report Contents\n");

                $intry  = (stream_get_contents($request->getReport()) . "\n");
                file_put_contents('inventory.csv',$intry);

                echo("            ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
     } catch (MarketplaceWebService_Exception $ex) {
         echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
         echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
         echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
         echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
         echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
         echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
         echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
     }
 }
```

Comment: I am facing the same,Can you please define  what resolution did you find for it?